# lua if else while statements limits?

Tags: if-statement, lua, computercraft

im trying to make a program for a lua based computer in a game. Although when its run it acts weird

```
--Tablet

    oldpullEvent = os.pullEvent
    os.pullEvent = os.pullEventRaw
    while true do
        term.clear()
        term.setTextColor( colors.white )
        term.setCursorPos(1, 1)
        print("Please Enter Password:")
        input = read("*")
        incorrect = 0
        while incorrect < 3 do
            if input == "qwerty" then
                print("Password Correct, Unlocking")

            else
                if incorrect < 3 then
                    incorrect = incorrect + 1
                    print("Password incorrect")
                    print(3 - incorrect, " tries remaining")
                else 
                    print(3 - incorrect, "tries remaining, locking phone for 1m")
                    local num = 0
                    while num < 60 do
                        if num < 60 then 
                            term.clear()
                            term.setTextColor( colors.red )
                            term.setCursorPos(1, 1)
                            num = num + 1
                            print(60 - num, "s remaining")
                            sleep(1)
                        else
                            incorrect = 0
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end 
    end
    os.pullEvent = oldpullEvent
```

When it runs it starts with
"Please enter password:"
upon entering "qwerty" the password it wants, it loops "Password Correct, Unlocking" over and over infinitly.
when I enter an incorrect password it doesnt run any of the code in the else statement and just returns back to the enter password screen. no error codes or crashes. Does anybody who know lua know if I wrote my while/if/elseif functions wrong or a work around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the correct password is entered the loop is not told to stop. After the correct password is entered a `break` should be placed after `print("Password Correct, Unlocking")`

This is because the `input` is outside the loop, a better approach would be something like this:

```
local incorrect = 0
while true do
    term.clear()
    term.setTextColor( colors.white )
    term.setCursorPos(1, 1)
    print("Please Enter Password:")
    local input = read("*")

    if input == "qwerty" then
        print("Password Correct, Unlocking")
        break
    else
        if incorrect < 2 then
            incorrect = incorrect + 1
            print("Password incorrect")
            print(3 - incorrect, " tries remaining")
            sleep(1) -- let them read the print.
        else
            print("out of attempts, locking phone for 1m")
            for i = 10, 1, -1 do
                term.clear()
                term.setTextColor( colors.red )
                term.setCursorPos(1, 1)
                print(i, "s remaining")
                sleep(1)
            end
            incorrect = 0
        end
    end
end
```

The above code will allow the user 3 attempts at the password, if all are used they are locked out for 60 seconds and given another 3 attempts. This repeats until the correct password is entered.

I have removed the inner while loop as it was not required. The `incorrect` has been made local and moved outside of the while loop so it doesn't get reset every time the user enters a password.

The `read("*")` has been moved inside the while loop so it prompts the user for a password every time rather than asking once and then looping infinitely.

The code has been tested and appears to work without any problems.

If any of the code doesn't make sense don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: It works great! only thing is I now do not know were i could put in the code thats supposed to be ran only after entering the correct password. would i put it before or after the break, or should i just make it a separate function that runs when the correct password is entered. i want to be able to run gui after this runs. a console.log would help to demonstrate if you could. Thanks!

Comment: @tecksup seeing as though the loop should never stop unless the password is correctly entered (the break keyword exits the loop) I would put the code under and outside of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset `incorrect` value after correct password is entered. You either need to use `break` to abort the loop or to set `incorrect` to 3 or larger value.